# Create Google cloud bucket with read for unauthenticated users via API

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I need to create a bucket via API, all files in it has to be visible (to read) for all users (even unauthenticated ones). I use PHP StorageClient

What I've tried:
Passing as $storageClient->createBucket options parameters

```
'iamConfiguration' => [
    "bindings" => [
        [
            "role" => "storage.objects.get",
            "members" =>["allUsers"]
        ]
    ]
],
```

or

```
'iamConfiguration' => [
    "bindings" => [
        [
            "role" => "roles/storage.objectViewer",
            "members" =>["allUsers"]
        ]
    ]
],
```

and

```
'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead',
```

or even

```
'acl' => [
    ['entity' => 'allUsers', 'role' => 'READER'] //.
]
```

And still, when I try to open file I get

> Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @alanmcknee could you please give it a try configuring your `binding` part like this `{ "bindings":[ { "role": "roles/storage.objectViewer", "members":["allUsers"] } ] }`? As per the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets), it seems that you are not setting it correctly.

Comment: @gso_gabriel well, I was, but trying through iamConfiguration field in options in createBucket resource. I had to pass an array there, and there's no info how should that look. But I figured it out

Comment: Hi @alanmcknee thanks for confirming that you could figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to send a next request after createBucket

```
$policy = new PolicyBuilder();
$policy->setBindings([
    ['role' => 'roles/storage.objectViewer', 'members' => ['allUsers']]
]);

$bucket->iam()->setPolicy($policy);
```